# PhpStorm file watcher for individual files on remote hosts

Tags: less, phpstorm

My file watchers are setup and working properly for all my projects with locally downloaded files, but when editing files opened with the 'Browse Remote Hosts' file explorer the file watchers are not being executed.

I have tried all scope settings for the file watcher, but it doesn't seem to be possible to get this working for individual remote files.

[image: File watcher settings]

Comment: AFAIK when you are editing file on remote host directly .. it's not treated as part of the project. So yeah -- File Watchers will not work for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remote file watchers are not supported, please follow [WEB-9724](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9724) for updates